# PyCharm: FooTestCase is no test, but FooTest is

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

If I call my test class `FooTestCase` I see no green play-buttons to run the test:

[image: code-without-green-play-buttons]

If I remove the "Case" and call it `FooTest` the green play buttons appear:

[image: code-with-green-play-buttons]

Why does this happen?

I would like to have the play-buttons to run the test for "FooTestCase".

Comment: That's an issue with PyCharm test-detection mechanism. Feel free to report it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY Is `testutils` an open source package or a project-specific module? Does `EditTestCase` directly inherit `unittest.TestCase`? Btw which test runner do you use?

Comment: @PavelKarateev I use pytest and Python 2.7. `testutils` is our code, and it inherits from unittest.TestCase

Comment: I can reproduce the problem only when PyCharm fails to resolve `testutils.EditTestCase`. This way it falls back to the class name (starts/ends with `Test`) to determine if it contains test methods as the IDE can't track down the inheritance back to `unittest.TestCase`. Not sure why it happens in your case, the concrete `testutils` structure is needed.

Comment: @PavelKarateev ok. let's focus on the fall-back. I think it would make sense to add `TestCase` to the check which triggers "is-a-test". The parent class has this name, and it is very usual to name a subclass like the parent. In this example EditTestCase

Comment: Fair enough, I created a ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39093 Please feel free to comment there if I misunderstood your idea.

Comment: @PavelKarateev thank you, I upvoted your issue.