# What is a "line marker" icon in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, gutter

What is this "line marker" icon in the gutter in PyCharm IDE?
When does it appear exactly?

I looked up but [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-gutter-icons.html) doesn't explain much about the icon itself.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *"Line Marker"* (or green run icon) in the gutter is added by PyCharm to special lines the IDE considers as runnable. This is not only the case for lines containing a [Top level script enviorment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) but also frequent with executable test functions from testing frameworks, for example with [pytest](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pytest.html#pytest-fixtures) among others.

The PyCharm IDE detects these automatically (for example by prefixing a function name with `test` and having a testing framework configurered). One good example of this is the following thread where the IDE makes a mistake detecting a line as runnable, see [PyCharm: FooTestCase is no test, but FooTest is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58853964).

Answer (score 3):

It represents the entry point into the application - the line that is first invoked when you run the code.

You have some options when you click on it to run the code in a number of ways, for example with profiling or debugging.